# Magnolia CMS: How to get locale-based excerpt for search result?

Tags: search, solr, internationalization, magnolia

With the search example snippet provided in the documentation

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Search#Search-Displayingpagesinthewebsiteworkspace

```
[#list searchResults as item]
    <a href="${cmsfn.link(item)}" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">${item.title!}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">${item.excerpt!}</p>
    </a>
[/#list]
```

the variable `${item.excerpt!}` returns the excerpts for **all languages**, not only the current locale. So if I have a page in German (de) and French (fr), this `${items.excerpt!}` contains and shows an indexed title element for example twice. Does Solr not extract and store the text separately per language?

`${item.title}` is shown in the correct language.

**How is it possible to just get the excerpt for the current locale?**

---

**DE search (showing also French text):**

[image]

---

**FR search (showing also German text):**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `excerpt` property isn't actually a property, but a result of the Jackrabbit `rep:excerpt()` function (see the [SearchTemplatingFunctions code](http://git.magnolia-cms.com/gitweb/?p=modules/templating-essentials.git;a=blob;f=magnolia-templating-essentials-models/src/main/java/info/magnolia/templating/functions/SearchTemplatingFunctions.java;h=03c49339041b8bc9aebaa06e52d3ed2602bc12d4;hb=HEAD#l141)), the short answer is **no, it's not possible**.

Anyway, you can always implement your own `SearchTemplatingFunctions` (and/or [ExcerptProvider](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExcerptProvider) for Jackrabbit).

Comment: Update for others who are looking for this feature: in case you are using Magnolia 5.4.5 Enterprise Edition, I just saw this Wiki page https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Localized+Search+with+Apache+Solr which covers the topic.